# Passing sql query result to textbox

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL DB, and I want to make a data displayer for my friend who doesn't know SQL but sometimes he need to get some information.

I want to write a Windows Forms application which should allow him to type some client id and in result give him some data about this client.

I wrote something like this (below) and I am stuck - after clicking a button I want to pass the answer of my query to a textBox and I can't, tried many solutions. None worked. Anyone can help ?

```
    private void btShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=someServer;Port=1234;User ID=some_user;Password=123456;Database=someDataBase;");
        conn.Open();

        NpgsqlCommand answer1 = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE id = :userId", conn);
        answer1.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("userId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
        answer1.Parameters[0].Value = tbId.Text;
   // HERE IS MY PROBLEM - How to pass the answer1 result to the textbox
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too much familiar with PostgresSQL but I think you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) method. It returns first column of the first row as an `object`.

If your `column1` is character type, you can use it like;

```
...
answer1.Parameters[0].Value = tbId.Text;
string s = (string)answer1.ExecuteScalar();
TextBox1.Text = s;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
NpgsqlDataReader reader = answer1.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.Read())
{
    yourTextBox.Text = reader["column1"].ToString();
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
yourTextBox.Text = answer1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

To pass text to a TextBox all you need to do is write:

```
TextBoxName.Text = yourVariable.ToString();
```

Comment: What is `yourVariable`? o.O

Comment: Sorry for beeing unclear, answer1.ToString() adds the variables value you your textbox. Using the above mentioned method ExecuteScalar().Tostring() does what you are asking. :)